# How to make your app graphically portable?

Tags: android

I'm new to developing Android games and I still don't have an idea as to how I can make the screen size for my game dynamic. Is this possible? Or do I really target a specific screen resolution? For example, if I have a 150 x 150 drawable in a 320 x 480 resolution, that would make the drawable large but what if the game is installed on a 1024 x 768 resolution? Any suggestions with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has several folders for different resolutions: `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, and, when using API-level 10 or higher, `xhdpi`.

The 320 x 480 resolution will use the mdpi folder, every step higher uses a factor of 1.5. So when your drawable is 150 x 150 in mdpi, you should make the drawable (150*1.5) x (150*1.5) = 225 x 225 for the hdpi folder.

You may also want to take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).